# Loop to generate PDFs but previous layer will not be removed

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pdf

I am new to GIS programming. I am trying to generate 5 unique PDFs, but the previous layer does not get removed before moving onto the next iteration. The results are 5 PDFs that are close, but have too many layers.  Here is the latest iteration of my attempts:

```
soils = ["California_Points_loam", "California_Points_clay_loam", "California_Points_sandy_clay_loam", "California_Points_clay_light", "California_Points_silt_loam"]

# set the path to the aprx file
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("C:/Users/Jon/Desktop/project.aprx")

# get the map object from the project
map = aprx.listMaps()[0]

# set a variable to store the last layer added to the map
last_layer = None

# get the layout object from the project
layout = aprx.listLayouts()[0]

# loop through the soils list
for soil in soils:
    # add a layer to the map object
    layer = map.addDataFromPath("C:/Users/Jon/Desktop/375.gdb/" + soil)
    
    # add the layer to the layout object
    mf = layout.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[0]
    mf.map.addLayer(layer)
    
    # export the layout to a PDF file with a unique name
    layout.exportToPDF("C:/Users/Jon/Desktop/375.gdb/" + soil + ".pdf")

    # remove the last layer added to the map, if any
    if last_layer:
        map.removeLayer(last_layer)
         
    # update the last_layer variable to the current layer
    last_layer = layer

    map.removeLayer(layer)

# save and close the project
aprx.save()
aprx.shutdown()
```

Comment: Don't know if this is the issue but its very bad practise to export your layout as a pdf into a geodatabase (375.gdb). Export it to a folder. I would also say its bad practise to name a geodatabase as such, ideally it should start with a letter, no weird characters or spaces.